# How to get a desired qubit trought Bloch Sphere rotations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, hilbert-space, bloch-sphere

Starting from the zero pure qubit, how can I get the normalized qubit $$ \alpha\left|0\right\gt + \beta\left|1\right\gt $$ such that $$ |\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = 1 $$ using the spherical coordinates $(\theta, \phi)$ on the Bloch Sphere. I suppose that those coordinates are calculated as

$$ (\theta, \phi) = \left(2 * \arctan\left(\frac{\text{module}(\beta)}{\text{module}(\alpha)}\right), \arg(\beta)- \arg(\alpha)\right) $$

and then I need to use the rotation matrices over the Bloch sphere axes.

\begin{align}
      R_x(\omega) &= \left( \begin{matrix}
        \cos\left(\frac{\omega}{2}\right) & -i\sin\left(\frac{\omega}{2}\right) \\
        -i\sin\left(\frac{\omega}{2}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{\omega}{2}\right)\\
        \end{matrix} \right)
\\
 R_y(\omega) &= \left(\begin{matrix}
\cos\left(\frac{\omega}{2}\right) & -\sin\left(\frac{\omega}{2}\right)\\
\sin\left(\frac{\omega}{2}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{\omega}{2}\right)\\
 \end{matrix}\right)
\\
 R_z(\omega) &= \left(\begin{matrix}
 e^{-i{\omega}/{2}} & 0\\
0 & e^{i{\omega}/{2}}\\
 \end{matrix}\right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with $\vert 0\rangle= \left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0\end{array}\right)$ and apply the sequence
\begin{align}
R_z(\phi)R_y(\theta)\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0\end{array}\right)
&=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 e^{-\frac{i \phi }{2}} \cos \left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) & -e^{-\frac{i \phi }{2}} \sin \left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) \\
 e^{\frac{i \phi }{2}} \sin \left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) & e^{\frac{i \phi }{2}} \cos \left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0\end{array}\right)\, ,\\
&=\left(\begin{array}{c}
e^{-\frac{i \phi }{2}} \cos \left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) \\
e^{\frac{i \phi }{2}} \sin \left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right)\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\alpha \\ \beta\end{array}\right)
\end{align}
from which it immediately follows that 
$$
\alpha=e^{-\frac{i\phi}{2}}\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\, ,\qquad
\beta=e^{\frac{i\phi}{2}}\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\, .
$$

Suppose now 
$$
\alpha= \frac{2+45 i}{3\sqrt{574}}=\sqrt{\frac{2029}{5166}}e^{i\varphi_a}\, ,\qquad
\beta= \frac{56+I}{3\sqrt{574}}=\sqrt{\frac{3137}{5166}}e^{i\varphi_b}
$$
where 
$$
\varphi_a=\arctan(45/2)\, ,\qquad \varphi_b=\arctan(1/56)
$$
Using
$$
\frac{\beta}{\alpha}=e^{i\phi}\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) 
$$
we obtain $\phi=-\arctan\left(\frac{2518}{157}\right)$ and
\begin{align}
R_z(\phi)R_y(\theta)\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right)&=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0.456729\, +0.429138 i & -0.567903-0.533597 i \\
 0.567903\, -0.533597 i & 0.456729\, -0.429138 i \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right)\, ,\\
&=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0.456729\, +0.429138 i\\ 0.567903\, -0.533597 i 
\end{array}\right)\
\end{align}
which differs from your target vector $(\alpha,\beta)$ by an unimportant overall phase $e^{2.02367 i}$.

Comment: I try this to get the qubit $$ (2 + 45i) |0 \gt +  (56 + i) |1 \gt $$ that has norm 71.8748, so the normalized qubit is $$ (0.02782612904 + 0.6260879034i) |0\gt + (0.7791316131 + 0.01391306452i) |1\gt $$ The spherical coordinates are $\theta = 1.786955007 $ and $\phi = -1.5085258$ The result of the rotations proposed are (0.45673-0.5679i) |0> + (-0.42914-0.5336i) |1> that it's different from the desired qubit.

Comment: @CodeSnifer: you were out by an overall phase.

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry, I'm a beginner in the subject. How can I correct that overall phase to get exactly the same amplitudes?

Comment: In QM, two vectors like $(\alpha,\beta)$ and $e^{i\xi}(\alpha,\beta)$ are physically equivalent (describe the same physics).  Your target vector is just

Comment: Your target vector is just ....?

Comment: $\left(\begin{array}{c}
0.456729\, +0.429138 i\\ 0.567903\, -0.533597 i 
\end{array}\right)$ is just $e^{i\xi} \times$ the vector you want.

Comment: That works. But, there is a way of determine ξ without resolving the equation $$ \left(    \begin{matrix} \lambda \\ \gamma  \end{matrix}\right) * e^{iξ} =   $$

Comment: $$= \left(\begin{matrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{matrix}\right) $$ For example in terms of the spherical coordinates.

Comment: $(\alpha^*,\beta^*)\left(\begin{array}{c}\lambda \\ \gamma \end{array}\right)\times e^{i\xi}= 1$

Comment: But that's equivalent to solve the citated equation. I guess if there is any way of getting ξ without knowing (λ γ). Or if you can do the rotations avoiding that global phase in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "rotations avoiding the global phase" because the global phase will not change the physics of the problem (i.e. states are rays, not vectors).  So I suppose yes you can do the rotation avoiding the global phase but you can NOT do the rotation since the state I obtained is entirely equivalent to the state you initially proposed.